# Find maximum value in each row or column of an Excel array

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, named

In Excel I have a named range that contains an array, for example like the array below.

```
0 0 0 7
0 0 6 5
0 5 3 2
4 3 2 1
```

I'd like to find the maximum value in each row (or column) of the array. For the columns in the array above I want the result to be:

```
Array={4,5,6,7}
```

If it helps, the maximum is always going to be the topmost number for a column and leftmost number for a row.

I would like a worksheet formula rather than a VBA function.

Comment: Do you happen to mean worksheet formula or VBA function? Your question implies VBA but the tags imply ws.

Comment: I assume you don't want a worksheet formula to literally output "Array={4,5,6,7}"? What is the context for wanting to do this?

Comment: @Steven No, I don't literally want "Array=" etc. I want an array with which I can do further calculations. I want that new array to only include the maximum values from each row or column of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

With a named range Rng and values as posted in original post try this formula.

```
=SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(INDEX(Rng,1,1),,COLUMN(Rng)-MIN(COLUMN(Rng)),ROWS(Rng)))
```

It returns an array of max of each column `{4,5,6,7}`

This returns a max of each row.

```
=SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(INDEX(Rng,1,1),ROW(Rng)-MIN(ROW(Rng)),,,COLUMNS(Rng)))
```

and an array `{7;6;5;4}.`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. If my initial array is named *rng* then the following array formula can be used to return an array showing the maximum number in each column:

```
=MAX(INDEX(rng,0,COLUMN(A1:D1)))
```

Similarly, to return the maximum in each row:

```
=MAX(INDEX(rng, ROW(A1:A4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

please note that

`=MAX(INDEX(rng, ROW(A1:A4)))`
and
`=MAX(INDEX(rng, ROW(A1:A4)))`

only work if your array starts in A1 as it is relative to the array not the position in the sheet